# Deploy user Github pages only after Travis tests passed

Tags: github, deployment, travis-ci, github-pages

I'm trying to deploy an User github page only after the execution of all the Travis tests. 
However, User pages must be built from the master branch and I need it to be built from the gh-pages if I want Travis to deploy once the tests passed.

The .travis.yml is:

```
language: node_js
node_js:
  - "8.1"
sudo: false
before_install:
  - rvm install 2.2.2
  - ./tool/before_install.sh

script: ./tool/travis.sh

deploy:
  provider: pages
  skip-cleanup: true
  github-token: $GITHUB_TOKEN  # Set in travis-ci.org dashboard, marked secure
  keep-history: true
  on:
    branch: master
```

This configuration file works fine when the gh-pages branch is the one the github page is built from, but when I switch my github page to an User page, I can't choose the gh-pages branch anymore, as shown here:

[image]

I tried to change the .travis.yml file:

```
    language: node_js
    node_js:
      - "8.1"
    sudo: false
    before_install:
      - rvm install 2.2.2
      - ./tool/before_install.sh

    script: ./tool/travis.sh

   branches:
    only:
     - gh-pages

    deploy:
      provider: pages
      skip-cleanup: true
      github-token: $GITHUB_TOKEN  # Set in travis-ci.org dashboard, marked secure
      keep-history: true
      on:
        branch: gh-pages
```

And then to git push on the gh-pages branch instead of the master hoping it will deploy then on the master one such as when I did git push to the master one and it deployed on the gh-pages, but it does not update the master one in this case and so, the modifications are not considered.

And also, when I tried not to use the gh-pages step, the changes were deployed by Github/pages before the end of the Travis tests, so the Github page was updated even if the tests failed.

Is there a way I did not think about to make this works?